# Table partition on non date column

Tags: oracle, partitioning

How can I partition a table in oracle on non-date column (Say partition on Username)?
I have table partitioning on only date columns.Say:

```
CREATE TABLE X
(
Username Varchar2(10 Char),
Import_date Date
)
PARTITION BY RANGE ("IMPORT_DATE") INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY')) 
 (PARTITION "CL_REP_DEF"  VALUES LESS THAN 
     (TO_DATE(' 2018-06-29 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
)
```

Though I am not sure how to partition with username here.

Comment: Hash partition?

Comment: There are several other options: RANGE (typically numeric values), LIST, HASH or even referenced to another table.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle offers three types of partitions:

- Range
- Hash
- List

You can use any of them.
Selection of partitioning type depends on the data stored in a table and values of partitioned column (columns). If the number of distinct values in a column (columns) is limited and known, then LIST type would be a better choice.

As to your case, I think HASH partition fits the most.
Here's an example of how you can partition your `X` table:

```
CREATE TABLE X
(
Username Varchar2(10 Char),
Import_date Date
) PARTITION BY HASH(Username) PARTITIONS 16; -- 16 is the number of partitions.
```

You can find more about partitioning in official [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm).